# How can I receive push notifications of an other app?

Tags: ios, notifications, push, pebble-watch

Most of you guys may know the pebble watch, this watch receives push notifictions of you phone.

They are capable of receiving some notifications.

- Incoming Caller ID
- Email (Gmail or any IMAP email account)
- SMS on both Android and iPhones
- iMessage (iOS only)
- Calendar Alerts
- Facebook Messages
- Twitter
- Weather Alerts
- Silent vibrating alarm and timer

How can I do the same?
Maybe they wrote some notifications their self using the facebook api or somthing like that.
But how to do this with sms and calls?

What notifications are you able to catch?

Comment: Any new updates regarding the same question ?
isn't there any straight way to get notification from other apps and storing them still.. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses Bluetooth and talks through that to access all that data. It does not do anything fancy. However, all of that data is coming from the OS, not from applications on the device.

To answer your question - there is no way to get all of these notifications in your own app. You can use the CoreTelephony to access some of the data related to incoming calls and you could integrate Facebook and Twitter APIs to get that data, but you really would have to do it all yourself. There's no silver bullet here unfortunately!

Comment: Ah okay, thx. I thought I could do some cool things with it but its a lot more work then I thought

Answer (score 8):

Pebble uses Bluetooth to communicate with smartphone.Please find the answers for iPhone(iOS6) and relevant links.

```
Incoming Caller ID                                 CoreTelephony Framewerk
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html

You have to use PBAP to show the callerID on the bluetooth device and the device has to be MFi to communicate with iPhone app.

```
Email (Gmail or any IMAP email account)            PushNotifications 
SMS and iMessage                                   PushNotifications with MAP
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

```
Calendar Alerts                                    EVentKit Framework
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EventKitFrameworkRef/_index.html

```
Facebook Messages                                  Social Framework
Twitter                                            Social Framework
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233

```
Weather Alerts                         Any weather API from yahoo or MSN
```

Following code  can be used to vibrate iPhone

Add AudioToolbox frame work import AudioServices.h

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

Answer (score 3):

Try to check out feature Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html