# Getting all of an iPhone's notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, pebble-watch

I noticed that the pebble smart match is able to get all of your notifications from your iPhone and display them on the device. How can it do that? Isn't the notifications center sandboxed and not in the API?

Comment: Duplicated ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291925/how-can-i-receive-push-notifications-of-an-other-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pebble uses the [ANCS service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html) to get all notifications. This service is only accessible through Bluetooth Low Energy.