# what is the way to get all apps notification alerts to my app from notification centre in ios 7 & 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm working on project which has tricky part. I want to get all notifications from Facebook, Whatsapp and some of the other app to my app notification centre from that i want to send data to the external peripheral device which will notify the user.

Comment: What you have tried, where you get the problem....???

Comment: i just want to know how should i do that, what is the procedure ???

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Also this is a duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291925/how-can-i-receive-push-notifications-of-an-other-app), so I'll quote from there.

> There is no way to get all of these notifications in your own app. You
>   can use the CoreTelephony to access some of the data related to
>   incoming calls and you could integrate Facebook and Twitter APIs to
>   get that data, but you really would have to do it all yourself.
>   There's no silver bullet here unfortunately!

Even if you used private API, its highly unlikely you'll find a way either, not to mention that your app will be rejected on the app store for using private API.